# How to identify multiple unsuccessful login attempts?

Tags: meteor

I would like to add an extra reCaptcha to my login form after several unsuccessful login attempts (let's say 3). My first idea was to use the `DDPRateLimiter` but it looks that it doesn't alter a method, it only limits the calls to it. The recaptcha should show up after, e.g. the third attempt, and it should be checked, I guess, in a server side `Accounts.onLogin()`  function.

I would like **to avoid logging user login attempts** and use a built-in features if possible. I mean that if `DDPRateLimiter` can spot the number of connections, isn't there a place where I could too (oplog?)? I am wondering if there is a common practice to achieve that, or if someone came up with a satisfying solution.

Of course, feel free to request more details.